# I need to happen a process between 2 given times in arduino

Tags: time, arduino, real-time-clock

In my project i have a function which i only need to execute if the current time is between given 2 times. Note that the time is fetched from RTC so its 24hr. For example if current time is 23:00,start time is 20:00 and end time is 5:00 the function must execute and not execute otherwise.

```
if((fromhour>=now.hour() && fromminute>=now.minute()) || (tohour>=now.hour() && tominute>=now.minute()))
{
     //Call function
}
```

I tried this code but not working as expected. please give a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Guys i think i find a solution for this.

```
starttime=fromhour*100+fromminute;
stoptime=tohour*100+tominute;
current_time=currenthour*100+currentminute;
if(current_time>=starttime && current_time<=stoptime)
{
    //Call function
}
```

Tell me if there is an improved or better way. Happy coding :)